# ERROR CS0120= Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo,método o propiedad c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scraping

Buen dia, he generado un scrapper para descargar un archivo, y he estado siguiendo una guía para descomprimir dicho archivo, pero ahora tengo el error del título y no sé a qué se debe. He tratado de buscar si es acaso como declaro las clases, si son estáticos. muestro la estructura en una imagen:
[image: codigo resumido]

y el código donde me marca error:

```
string getyear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                string getmonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
                string getday = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
                name = "PTI151101TE5_" + getyear + getmonth + getday;// +
 string path = "C:\\Users\\Monster\\Downloads";
                if (Directory.Exists(path)) //we check if the directory or folder exists
                {
                    bool result = CheckFile(name); // boolean result true or false is stored after checking the zip file name
                    if (result == true)
                    {
                        ExtractFiles();// if the zip file is present , this method is called to extract files within the zip file
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // if the zip file is not present, then the  test fails
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //if the directory or folder does not exist, then the test fails
                }
```

Captura que arroja el compilador de mis errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: o pones los metodos estaticos, o los mandas a una clase e instancias antes la clase... lee sobre metodos estaticos y no estaticos..

Comment: Lee la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120 ... Si no entiendes algo, edita tu pregunta y agrega la duda que tengas.

Answer (score 0):

Mi error como me sugerieron estaba en métodos estaticos y dinámicos; aunque también otro error por el cuál no quedaba a pesar que hiciera la correcta declaración de los métodos, se encontraba en como había construido el webdriver.
[image: solucion]

Aquí muestro como tenía el IwebDriver anteriormente y por el cuál a pesar de declarar bien los métodos, no compilaba el proyecto:

```
        using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)))
        { //aqui tenia todo mi codigo,llamando a los metodos y no compilaban}
```

y ahora cambiando esa parte del código:

```
// Initialize the Chrome Driver Get zip file
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

//y seguia el código, sin declararlo de manera interna del IwebDriver

esto dentro del Main. Espero haber explicado mayormente la solución gracias a los comentarios aportados.